# Live update select

Tags: php, jquery, select

I'm new to Jquery... I have a select listing all the files within a directory (listing done in php) and an upload form on the same page adding files to this directory.

I am looking for a way to update the select listing without refreshing the page when the uplo
ad is complete (I have an onComplete function). I have looked into the .live() method without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think AJAX is your answer. Read the documentation http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

You have to write a PHP function to get the list of new files, run the AJAX request to get this new list when `onComplete` then update your HTML using these new elements :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to get the new list when onComplete after the AJAX request. The list displays in a textbox for the moment as I don't know how to display it in the select: `document.getElementById('fontlisting') = ajaxRequest.responseText;`. Any idea please?

Comment: Found the solution. My option group id in the select is "uploaded", the correct javascript is: `document.getElementById('uploaded').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;`. Thanks again for your help